# Automating TXT file import to xls with Specifications in excel or access

Tags: excel, vba, csv, ms-access, import

I have about ~900 CSV files, all of which are exported from a tracking software.  Unfortunately, this software imports about 52 or so lines of summary data in rows on top of the frame by frame data that has many headings.

What I'm looking for is a way to:

1)Open the csv file

2)Save summary data as a separate spreadsheet with the file name "Original_Summary"

3)Save frame by frame data (with headers included) into a separate Excel file with the original file name as the new name of the worksheet.

Previously, I had manually done this cut/paste for each of them with ~124 files, but since the number of files has gotten so out of hand, I'm not sure that doing this manually is the best option.

I have another script that I've already written that imports these excel files as separate tables into Access, but now I need a way to transfer them from the CSV with all of the extra summary data at the top moved into a separate file.

Is there a way that I can do this?

Thanks!

```
Sub ImportManyTXTs_test()
Dim strFile As String
Dim foldername As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
strFile = Dir("C:\Users\Jared\Desktop\Processed\Text\*.txt")
Do While strFile <> vbNullString
Set ws = Sheets.Add
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
   "TEXT;" & "C:\Users\Jared\Desktop\Processed\Text\" & strFile, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = strFile
    '.FieldNames = True
    '.RowNumbers = False
    '.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    '.PreserveFormatting = True
    '.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    '.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    '.SavePassword = False
    '.SaveData = True
    '.AdjustColumnWidth = True
    '.RefreshPeriod = 0
    '.TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    '.TextFilePlatform = 437
    '.TextFileStartRow = 52
    '.TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    '.TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    '.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    '.TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    '.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    '.TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    '.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    '.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlYMDFormat, 1, 1)
    '.TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(22, 13, 13)
    '.TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    '.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    '.CommandType = 0
    '.Name = "T15_070916_B"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 52
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With
ActiveSheet.Name = strFile
strFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

I've tried this, and it does not seem to upload all of my files, only the first 99 or so, and it also will not import them into a new workbook, rather only a new worksheet with the original extension.  For some reason, it also only works 1 time before I have to delete the file and start over.  Which is odd.

I'm still kind of new to coding, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Start with Recording a macro for what you do manually? Then make use of loops to open all the files.

Comment: So when I tried this, I ran into the issue of the program adding each of the files directly to the workbook as a new worksheet, and with the filename & extension which I did not want.  I wanted to make each of them their own workbook, with the worksheet retaining the original filename and I am not seeing how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an SQL and QueryTable solution. Using the ACE Engine (Windows .dll files), you can query a csv file, particularly running `SELECT TOP 52 *` for top summary rows and then use a QueryTable for bottom rows starting at row 53 (as ACE SQL does not have the `BOTTOM` predicate).

Below sets up function for both Top and Bottom sections with a macro creatig a workbook and worksheets, then calling these methods in a loop:

```
Sub ExtractCSV()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim strfile As String, strpath As String

    strpath = "C:\Users\Jared\Desktop\Processed\Text\"
    strfile = Dir("C:\Users\Jared\Desktop\Processed\Text\*.txt")

    Do While strfile <> vbNullString
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add()

        wb.Sheets(1).Name = "Original Summary"
        wb.Sheets.Add After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        wb.Sheets(2).Name = "Frame"

        Call TopSummary(wb, strpath, strfile)
        Call BottomFrame(wb, strpath, strfile)

        wb.SaveAs strpath & "\" & Replace(strfile, ".csv", ".xlsx"), xlWorkbookDefault
        wb.Close True

        strfile = Dir
    Loop

    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub

Function TopSummary(currwb As Workbook, strpath As String, strfile As String)
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' CONNECTION STRING
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source=" & strpath & ";" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"""

    ' OPEN DB CONNECTION
    conn.Open strConnection     

    ' QUERY CSV
    strSQL = " SELECT TOP 52 * FROM " & strfile

    ' OPEN QUERY RECORDSET
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    currwb.Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    currwb.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True

    rst.Close: conn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing

End Function

Function BottomFrame(currwb As Workbook, strpath As String, strfile As String)
    Dim qt As QueryTable

    ' ADD QUERYTABLE
    With currwb.Sheets(2).QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strpath & "\" & strfile, _
        Destination:=currwb.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1))
            .TextFileStartRow = 53
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False

            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ' REMOVE QUERYTABLE
    For Each qt In currwb.Sheets(2).QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt

    Set qt = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Okay, I messed up in the original post.  I meant to say that they were .txt files, but they are delimited text.  I will try this to see if it works!

One thing I am looking to try to do is keep the original file name (without the .txt) for the worksheet names for each file in the loop, and for the worksheet that has the summary I want it to be "[original file name here]_Summary".

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So when running this code, I ran into 2 issues.

First

Comment: So when running this code, I ran into 2 issues
    wb.SaveAs strpath & "\" & Replace(strfile, ".csv", ".xlsx"), xlWorkbookDefault

I replaced .csv with .txt to see if that would work since the files are all saved as .txt files...but it keeps throwing back an error code saying that the file cannot be accessed.

Second, in the bottom frame function, the ".Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False" is also throwing back an error code... Runtime 1004 error

Comment: Okay, so I found a StackOverflow question that someone suggested to just use "wb.SaveAs" instead of the long path name, but that just repeated the first file over and over again, and only added in the summary for that instead of the frame by frame...

Comment: What is the delimiter in txt file? Tab? Comma? Semicolon? Yes, it should be .csv, but not sure why you get error if you changed to .txt, might related to the querytable error. Do note *strpath* being concatenated also in file name.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, was out of my office for a few days.  My delimiter is tab.  is there a specific way to call a tab delimter instead of comma delimited in this line:  
`" strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source=" & strpath & ";" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,);"""`

Comment: Okay, so I've gotten it to loop through all of the files, update the filenames as I need them, etc.

However, no data is coming into the worksheets!  and Excel is opening a new workbook for each of the files (which I assume when I run this with 900 total files, it would kill my computer).  Is there a work-around for this?  

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: So you want 900 worksheets in one workbook? See update with slight change in SQL and QueryTable from comma to tab delimited spec. Also, a `.TextToColumns` is added if query does not map content to multiple cells.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Parfait, I was able to develop some code that did what I wanted it to do.

```
  Sub ExtractCSV()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook



    Dim strfile As String, strpath As String

'Adjust the line below to have the appropriate folder directory, changing from new folder to something

    strpath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Processed\Text\"
    strfile = Dir("C:\Users\me\Desktop\Processed\Text\*.txt")

    Do While strfile <> vbNullString

        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=strpath & strfile, Origin:= _
        437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
        , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), _
        Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), _
        Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array( _
        16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), _
        Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array( _
        29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), Array(32, 1), Array(33, 1), Array(34, 1), Array(35, 1), _
        Array(36, 1), Array(37, 1), Array(38, 1), Array(39, 1), Array(40, 1), Array(41, 1), Array( _
        42, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(44, 1), Array(45, 1), Array(46, 1), Array(47, 1), Array(48, 1), _
        Array(49, 1), Array(50, 1), Array(51, 1), Array(52, 1), Array(53, 1), Array(54, 1), Array( _
        55, 1), Array(56, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(58, 1), Array(59, 1), Array(60, 1), Array(61, 1), _
        Array(62, 1), Array(63, 1), Array(64, 1), Array(65, 1), Array(66, 1), Array(67, 1), Array( _
        68, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(70, 1), Array(71, 1), Array(72, 1), Array(73, 1), Array(74, 1), _
        Array(75, 1), Array(76, 1), Array(77, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        Set y = ActiveWorkbook

        'Adjust the line below to have the appropriate folder directory, changing from new folder to something

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\me\Desktop\New folder\todelete\" & strfile, FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

        Set wb = Workbooks.Add()


        wb.Sheets(1).Name = Left(strfile, Len(strfile) - 4)
        wb.Sheets.Add After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        wb.Sheets(2).Name = Left(strfile, Len(strfile) - 4) & "_Original_Summary"


        y.Sheets(Left(strfile, Len(strfile) - 4)).Rows("1:51").Copy
        'y.Sheets(Left(strfile, Len(strfile) - 4)).Selection.Copy
        wb.Sheets(Left(strfile, Len(strfile) - 4) & "_Original_Summary").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        y.Sheets(Left(strfile, Len(strfile) - 4)).Rows("52:1600").Copy
        'y.Sheets(Left(strfile, Len(strfile) - 4)).Selection.Copy
        wb.Sheets(Left(strfile, Len(strfile) - 4)).Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        y.Application.CutCopyMode = False
        y.Close True

        'Call TopSummary(wb, strpath, strfile)
        'Call BottomFrame(wb, strpath, strfile)

        'wb.SaveAs strpath & "\" & Replace(strfile, ".txt", ".xlsx"), xlWorkbookDefault
        wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\me\Desktop\New folder\" & Left(strfile, Len(strfile) - 4) & ".xlsx"

        wb.Close True

        strfile = Dir
    Loop

    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

The only thing that I am afraid of is that this may use a lot of resources.  Hopefully it doesn't, but on the few files I tested this on, it worked!